# How can I statistic instance numbers of each class and the memory they consumed in the peak time in native C++ project

Tags: c++, memory, class-instance-variables

My compiler project has a serious memory-consuming. So I want to find a method that can find out which class is the worst one. It should give me something like bellow:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Class name, Instance count, Peak memory consumed

Circle, 223, 2230 k

Rectangle, 124, 3220 k

Line, 22322, 222322 k

....., ...,   .... .
```

I have searched for a long time on the web but no result so far. :(

I have tried Devpartner tools. It can't deal with native C++ as I know. Does that because of I don't know how to use it?

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: To get the instance count of your objects just add a static counter to each class and at each call of `constructor()` increment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse I hope you are talking of Dynamically allocated memory.

You should use memory profiling tools.
If not you should overload the `new and`delete` operators for your own class and implement the memory count mechanism in the same.

Comment: Yes, most of memory was dynamically allocated. But I didn't overload new and delete operators for each class.

Comment: He should derive from a custom Object class, new and delete operators might have padding that can make it impossible to decide what objects the compiler wants to place in the allocated memory.

Comment: recently,I found a tool -- memoryvalidator. It solve my problem. It's the most powerfull memory profiling tool  that I have ever seen on windows.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a memory leak detector or a garbage collector. Personally I use the Boehm GC as garbage collector, but it is possible to use it as a leak detector. My friend uses valgrind for memory leak detection.

It is also possible to derive all of your classes from a custom Object, which keeps track of ALL allocated objects in a static std::set structure; the constructor inserts "this" into this structure, the destructor removes it. Then you can use a static Object::detectMemoryLeaks() at the end of your program to print out all leaking objects and their typeid(ptr).name().

Edit:

I implemented my version in the last few hours into my library. Found no way yet to exclude static variables, or to automatically determine the size of a polymorphic object. Also, please excuse the java-like alienish code and the presence of garbage collection: [header](http://frigocoder.dyndns.org/svn/Frigo/Lang/Object) and [implementation](http://frigocoder.dyndns.org/svn/Frigo/Lang/Object.cpp). Look for the constructor, the destructor, the aliveObjects static attribute and the listAliveObjects static method. You can get the gist of the concept easily.

Example outputs:

```
Frigo::Lang::Array<char> : 6 objects
Frigo::Lang::String : 6 objects
Frigo::Lang::Boolean : 2 objects
Frigo::Lang::Integer : 2 objects
Frigo::Math::Infinity : 1 objects
Frigo::Lang::Class : 1 objects

----

Frigo::Lang::Array<char> : 7 objects @ 0x1d33e18, 0x1d33e78, 0x1d33ed8, 0x1d33f38, 0x1d33f68, 0x1d33f98, 0x1d33fc8
Frigo::Lang::String : 7 objects @ 0x1d33e10, 0x1d33e70, 0x1d33ed0, 0x1d33f30, 0x1d33f60, 0x1d33f90, 0x1d33fc0
Frigo::Lang::Boolean : 2 objects @ 0x1d30fa8, 0x1d30fd8
Frigo::Lang::Integer : 2 objects @ 0x1d30e88, 0x1d30eb8
Frigo::Lang::Class : 1 objects @ 0x1d30f60
Frigo::Math::Infinity : 1 objects @ 0x41a110

----

Frigo::Lang::Array<char> : 6 objects
    Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@3b3e78
    Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@3b3ed8
    Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@3b3f38
    Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@3b3f68
    Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@3b3f98
    Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@3b3fc8
Frigo::Lang::String : 6 objects
    Frigo::Lang::Boolean
    Frigo::Lang::Class
    Frigo::Lang::Integer
    Hello World!
    true
    false
Frigo::Lang::Boolean : 2 objects
    true
    false
Frigo::Lang::Integer : 2 objects
    987
    123
Frigo::Math::Infinity : 1 objects
    Frigo::Math::Infinity@41a110
Frigo::Lang::Class : 1 objects
    Frigo::Lang::Class@3b0f60

----

Frigo::Lang::Array<char> : 7 objects
    @ 0x1cd3e18 : Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@1cd3e18
    @ 0x1cd3e78 : Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@1cd3e78
    @ 0x1cd3ed8 : Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@1cd3ed8
    @ 0x1cd3f38 : Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@1cd3f38
    @ 0x1cd3f68 : Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@1cd3f68
    @ 0x1cd3f98 : Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@1cd3f98
    @ 0x1cd3fc8 : Frigo::Lang::Array<char>@1cd3fc8
Frigo::Lang::String : 7 objects
    @ 0x1cd3e10 : Frigo::Lang::Boolean
    @ 0x1cd3e70 : Frigo::Lang::Class
    @ 0x1cd3ed0 : Frigo::Lang::Integer
    @ 0x1cd3f30 : Frigo::Math::Infinity
    @ 0x1cd3f60 : Hello World!
    @ 0x1cd3f90 : true
    @ 0x1cd3fc0 : false
Frigo::Lang::Boolean : 2 objects
    @ 0x1cd0fa8 : true
    @ 0x1cd0fd8 : false
Frigo::Lang::Integer : 2 objects
    @ 0x1cd0e88 : 987
    @ 0x1cd0eb8 : 123
Frigo::Lang::Class : 1 objects
    @ 0x1cd0f60 : Frigo::Lang::Class@1cd0f60
Frigo::Math::Infinity : 1 objects
    @ 0x41b110 : Frigo::Math::Infinity@41b110
```

Comment: From his question it does not seem that he has a leak but rather wants to find out the size of his objects.

Comment: Wasn't obvious from his question. But my method (renamed to listAliveObjects :) still stands, he just have to manually calculate the consumed memory from the instance count, or implement a dynamic sizeof... somehow...

Answer (score 0):

You can try atomically incrementing (InterlockedIncrement in win32) a static int declared in your class in the class' constructor and atomically decrementing it in the class' destructor. Then you can use another static method to retrieve the count and the total memory consumed.

Assuming you have a small number of suspect classes, this shouldn't take more than reasonable amount of coding effort.